# Web pages which works fine in Firefox shows some styling issues in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I am newbie to web development, in specific browser related css compatibility issues.

I have the following css in my home page, which works fine in Firefox, and I can see the css properties when I inspect the element using firebug. But the same css rules are missing when I use chrome. when I inspect, I can't even see the rules in chrome. I wonder why this happens. I understand that some css rules are browser dependent. But now am really confused by thinking how could I resolve this.

Please refer to this [link](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/2649626) to see my css rules.

Any suggestions regarding why and how this happens. Any useful link also will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the console in Chrome show any errors?

Comment: no.. it is not showing any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a media query, selecting only webkit specific stuff such as:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  /* Your CSS */
}
```

This query checks the device pixel ratio in webkit. Safari & Chrome are the only big browsers using webkit, so this will not affect FireFox or IE.